# rpm cx_oracle compatible oracle 21

Tags: python, oracle

I upgrade to oracle 21 and I need an rpm cx_oracle compatible oracle 21 for my script python.
ps: I can't use python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade --user

if you have another rpm instead of rpm cx_oracle to connect to db it will be useful also

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a specific oracle-21 [new] feature that your script is using?

Comment: which version of cx_oracle do you have?

Comment: currently I use cx_Oracle-12c-py27.x86_64       5.3-1.el7

Comment: which linux are you using? In Oracle Linux 7, I see this in the repo: 
python36-cx_Oracle.x86_64    8.2.1-1.el7   ol7_developer

Comment: Don’t forget that your cx_oracle rpm also has to match your python version. The old version would be python-2.7 the current version python-3.6 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute `ldd` on this driver you will find that this driver does not have link time dependency on `libclntsh.so`. It uses `dlopen` to loacate and dynamically load Oracle's client library (potentially of any version).

Oracle OCI C interface is very strict about backward compatibility.
So unless you really demand some 21c OCI feature you really do not need to upgrade cx_Oracle drivers.

"Any" version of cx_Oracle should be able to load latest libclntsh.so from Oracle 21c client/database installation.